# How to know the transferred duration?

Tags: silverlight, service, dns, ria, profiler

I'm making a Silverlight profiler to know some information on RIA Services Domain Service Request like request's duration, response's size, etc.

But I have a problem to find how much time it takes for the response to be completely downloaded on the client side (Silverlight app).

I found there is a progress event, but it's in a private class. I don't know where to find the BeginGetResponse event and the StopGetResponse event (or some information like this).

Any idea to do that ?

Thanks a lot.

Cedric